# Switch not working within while loop (Wordpress PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, while-loop, switch-statement

I've tried what I could on this and am still stuck, so I'm looking for some help. I'm sure there's something small I'm overlooking or am not aware of, so I'd be grateful for another set of eyes to take a look!

I'm trying to use a switch within a Wordpress while loop to set dimensions on post thumbnails for specific posts. The switch uses an auto-incrementing value ($count). Inside the loop, $count will return the right number for div ID's, but it will not work with the switch. All of the thumbnails go to the size defined before the loop begins (see $thumbsize)

Here's the code:

```
// Setup loop to pull only posts tagged slider
$max = 6;
$args = array('tag' => 'slider','posts_per_page' => $max);
$featuredPosts = new WP_Query();
$featuredPosts->query($args);

// Defaults for post thumbnail display
$thumbargs = array('class' => 'featured-blocks-img');
$thumbsize = array(640,360);

$count = 0;

    // Begin loop
    if ($featuredPosts->have_posts()) : while ($featuredPosts->have_posts()) : $featuredPosts->the_post();

    $count++;

    // Get post category and format for div class name
    $category = get_the_category();
    $catname = $category[0]->cat_name;
    $catdash = 'cat-';
    $catdash .= str_replace(' ', '-', $category[0]->cat_name);
    $catdash = strtolower($catdash);

    // Change post thumbnail size conditionally
    switch ($count) {
        case 2:
        case 5:
        case 6:
            $thumbsize == array(320,260);
            break;
        default:
            $thumbsize == array(640,360);
    } // End switch
    ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <div id="home-featured-post-<?php echo $count;?>" class="featured-blocks-post <?php echo $catdash; ?>">
            <h2 class="home-featured-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail($thumbsize, $thumbargs); ?>
        </div>      
    </a>

    <?php
    endwhile;
    endif; // End loop
```

And here it is in Gist form if that's helpful to anyone: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8984741

I tried to add comments that would provide some context.

Any ideas of what's happening? I can provide the resulting HTML source if that would help also.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your error log?

Comment: I checked WP_debug and server error log and there aren't any relevant messages to this function or even this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you aren't actually setting $thumbsize in the below code

```
$thumbsize == array(320,260);
```

== is comparing $thumbsize to that array, not creating an array with those values.

You really want it to just look like this:

```
$thumbsize = array(320,260);
```

Comment: Changing it to `$thumbsize = array(320,260);` worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't mind, could you explain to me why that change worked? I thought I understood the difference between =, ==, and === but perhaps not...

Comment: Sure thing. = is assigning a value to an item. So, if you were to say $i = 3; then echo $i your code would print '3'. == is comparing the items on each side. == is most commonly used in an if statement, like if($i == 3){ echo "yay! i equals 3!"; }else { echo "Boo! i is not equal to 3"; } In your code, you already set $thumbsize to something and then when you use your ==, it's not reassigning it, it's comparing it. So, the value of $thumbsize is never actually being changed.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense. Thank you so much!